# wordpress: echo custom field into WP_query array

Tags: wordpress

I have a basic query that displays latest news, but I added a custom field in the post editor so the user can define the Post ID's of the specific latest news they want to display.

```
$relatedpostnums = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'relatedpostnums', true);
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__in' => array( 31,7,53,35 ) ) ); while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

I have 31,7,53,35 as the posts I want to display. that is manually entered. If I want it to be dynamic, how do I replace those 4 numbers with the output from $relatedpostnums?

I did this (replaced the 4 numbers with $relatedpostnums):

```
$relatedpostnums = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'relatedpostnums', true);
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__in' => array( $relatedpostnums ) ) ); while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

But it only displays the first number, even if I set it to posts_per_page to 4

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `get_post_meta == true` mean that the function will return a single result, as a string (the latest ID for you).

Make it false or not will return an array

[See this reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)